Making two boxplots in one figure doesn't work in python
I've been facing the problem which is not able to check two box plot in one figure in python. (Dataframes of the two box are different as well.)
I do not know the reason of this problem, even though I've tried to check the dataframes, and the range of the data.
Here's what I can tell you guys.
cluster_data = df_encoded[df_encoded['dbscan_cluster'] != -1]

cluster_data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 1085 entries, 0 to 1204
Data columns (total 17 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------             --------------  -----  
 0   본사정원수              1085 non-null   float64
 1   본사휴가자수             1085 non-null   float64
 2   본사출장자수             1085 non-null   float64
 3   본사시간외근무명령서승인건수     1085 non-null   float64
 4   현본사소속재택근무자수        1085 non-null   float64
 5   중식계                1085 non-null   float64
 6   석식계                1085 non-null   float64
 7   month              1085 non-null   float64
 8   요일_금               1085 non-null   bool   
 9   요일_목               1085 non-null   bool   
 10  요일_수               1085 non-null   bool   
 11  요일_월               1085 non-null   bool   
 12  요일_화               1085 non-null   bool   
 13  조식메뉴_Main_encoded  1085 non-null   int64  
 14  중식메뉴_Main_encoded  1085 non-null   int64  
 15  석식메뉴_Main_encoded  1085 non-null   int64  
 16  dbscan_cluster     1085 non-null   int64  
dtypes: bool(5), float64(8), int64(4)
memory usage: 115.5 KB

noise_data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 77 entries, 2 to 994
Data columns (total 17 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------             --------------  -----  
 0   본사정원수              77 non-null     float64
 1   본사휴가자수             77 non-null     float64
 2   본사출장자수             77 non-null     float64
 3   본사시간외근무명령서승인건수     77 non-null     float64
 4   현본사소속재택근무자수        77 non-null     float64
 5   중식계                77 non-null     float64
 6   석식계                77 non-null     float64
 7   month              77 non-null     float64
 8   요일_금               77 non-null     bool   
 9   요일_목               77 non-null     bool   
 10  요일_수               77 non-null     bool   
 11  요일_월               77 non-null     bool   
 12  요일_화               77 non-null     bool   
 13  조식메뉴_Main_encoded  77 non-null     int64  
 14  중식메뉴_Main_encoded  77 non-null     int64  
 15  석식메뉴_Main_encoded  77 non-null     int64  
 16  dbscan_cluster     77 non-null     int64  
dtypes: bool(5), float64(8), int64(4)
memory usage: 8.2 KB


min(cluster_data['중식계']), max(cluster_data['중식계'])
(0.0, 1.0)

cluster_data['중식계'].unique()
array([0.638865  , 0.49097163, 0.58641445, 0.54084265, 0.52708512,
       0.83576956, 0.61736887, 0.53310404, 0.52794497, 0.40154772,
       0.86156492, 0.51848667, 0.62424764, 0.53396389, 0.40412726,
       0.49269132, 0.71453138, 0.46517627, 0.88564058, 0.62768702,
       0.52020636, 0.47377472, 0.37145314, 0.85124678, 0.56921754,
       0.60361135, 0.46087704, 0.39638865, 0.6311264 , 0.57351677,
       0.49871023, 0.48581255, 0.77128117, 0.51246776, 0.41702494,
       0.31384351, 0.80911436, 0.4677558 , 0.47893379, 0.40240757,
       0.79879622, 0.40842648, 0.57867584, 0.70851247, 0.58813414,
       0.47549441, 0.55374033, 0.34565778, 0.80051591, 0.42906277,
       0.62940671, 0.44282029, 0.3061049 , 0.81341359, 0.57437661,
       0.36715391, 0.79105761, 0.6122098 , 0.5322442 , 0.39294927,
       0.39982803, 0.76010318, 0.48151333, 0.51762683, 0.30696475,
       0.74290628, 0.69733448, 0.55202064, 0.41874463, 0.31298366,
       0.80395529, 0.53740327, 0.47635426, 0.36543422, 0.81513328,
       0.54600172, 0.45829751, 0.34479794, 0.81427343, 0.59157352,
       0.43336199, 0.3422184 , 0.73086844, 0.68357696, 0.49957008,
       0.43766122, 0.72742906, 0.4505589 , 0.50730868, 0.50128977,
       0.85640585, 0.56405847, 0.55288048, 0.48237317, 0.48753224,
       0.70421324, 0.53568358, 0.49011178, 0.74118659, 0.50902837,
       0.47119518, 0.37575236, 0.67927773, 0.54256234, 0.49527085,
       0.44711952, 0.32244196, 0.65262253, 0.43508169, 0.2966466 ,
       0.63800516, 0.49699054, 0.46947549, 0.47205503, 0.35425623,
       0.5399828 , 0.55631986, 0.39380911, 0.83404987, 0.7300086 ,
       0.55460017, 0.50644884, 0.44453998, 0.82717111, 0.56491831,
       0.74634566, 0.41960447, 0.54170249, 0.3972485 , 0.33190026,
       0.8383491 , 0.66380052, 0.51160791, 0.361135  , 0.76440241,
       0.63370593, 0.71539123, 0.64316423, 0.47033534, 0.83061049,
       0.89423904, 0.56319862, 0.64918315, 0.77386071, 0.60017197,
       0.54772141, 0.42218401, 0.39896819, 0.75236457, 0.47979364,
       0.43938091, 0.37403267, 0.79793637, 0.68013758, 0.61049011,
       0.48839209, 0.43594153, 0.7394669 , 0.59329321, 0.53654342,
       0.8288908 , 0.53138435, 0.5038693 , 0.37317283, 0.80739467,
       0.64488392, 0.49355116, 0.36457438, 0.81685297, 0.51934652,
       0.56749785, 0.69991402, 0.54514187, 0.51504729, 0.2794497 ,
       0.66466036, 0.40756664, 0.5227859 , 0.34651763, 0.79019776,
       0.42476354, 0.19604471, 0.22699914, 0.77042132, 0.45313844,
       0.35683577, 0.31126397, 0.84006879, 0.64058469, 0.56147893,
       0.60533104, 0.45915735, 0.8822012 , 0.76526225, 0.58469475,
       0.63542562, 0.35511608, 0.73602752, 0.58297506, 0.8116939 ,
       0.60963027, 0.87962167, 0.7033534 , 0.43078246, 0.9183147 ,
       0.6027515 , 0.57781599, 0.60877042, 0.72656922, 0.65434222,
       0.87274291, 0.56577816, 0.31642304, 0.85898538, 0.58125537,
       0.57179708, 0.28288908, 0.88736028, 0.52880482, 0.29922614,
       0.57953568, 0.5760963 , 0.29492691, 0.4411006 , 0.65692175,
       0.51676698, 0.26311264, 0.7927773 , 0.5133276 , 0.21066208,
       0.46689596, 0.49441101, 0.35855546, 0.21582115, 0.69905417,
       0.42562339, 0.42304385, 0.23989682, 0.19690456, 0.07480653,
       0.42648323, 0.44797936, 0.77987962, 0.51074807, 0.42992261,
       0.31470335, 0.783319  , 0.50988822, 0.47807395, 0.46603611,
       0.25881341, 0.45141874, 0.72570937, 0.71367154, 0.58985383,
       0.49785039, 0.26913156, 0.73172829, 0.58211522, 0.44539983,
       0.34307825, 0.57265692, 0.52966466, 0.27257094, 0.67755804,
       0.53482373, 0.74978504, 0.39036973, 0.30266552, 0.70765262,
       0.45657782, 0.43680138, 0.17626827, 0.55803955, 0.38607051,
       0.43250215, 0.31986242, 0.5588994 , 0.41358555, 0.35597592,
       0.34049871, 0.80481513, 0.65090284, 0.25623388, 0.76956148,
       0.53826311, 0.90627687, 0.59931212, 0.48495271, 0.78933792,
       0.37747206, 0.69045572, 0.52106621, 0.25193465, 0.59587274,
       0.75408426, 0.47463457, 0.20378332, 0.45399828, 0.73430782,
       0.56663801, 0.44625967, 0.74892519, 0.41616509, 0.28718831,
       0.61994841, 0.3783319 , 0.29578676, 0.22957868, 0.66122098,
       0.38177128, 0.7472055 , 0.50558899, 0.27687016, 0.73344798,
       0.36027515, 0.23129837, 0.01289768, 0.08426483, 0.73258813,
       0.50472915, 0.40068788, 0.75838349, 0.48925193, 0.32932072,
       0.82545142, 0.30782459, 0.81255374, 0.36629407, 0.9638865 ,
       0.65176268, 0.60705073, 0.92519347, 0.67841788, 0.36801376,
       0.82115219, 0.69561479, 0.5950129 , 0.30524506, 0.54858126,
       0.18228719, 0.9105761 , 0.62252794, 0.91573517, 0.56061909,
       0.35339639, 0.74204643, 0.6844368 , 0.39810834, 0.84264832,
       0.55030095, 0.27515047, 0.78761823, 0.52192605, 0.38263113,
       0.84866724, 0.48065348, 0.77300086, 0.47291488, 0.26569218,
       0.3250215 , 0.28632846, 0.72312984, 0.8022356 , 0.21238177,
       0.86844368, 0.30352537, 0.78675838, 0.28804815, 0.80137575,
       0.52364574, 0.22012038, 0.61564918, 0.18142734, 0.58383491,
       0.68873603, 0.24849527, 0.6577816 , 0.70507309, 0.38865004,
       0.16595013, 0.59759243, 0.35941531, 0.20980224, 0.41014617,
       0.51590714, 0.216681  , 0.40928633, 0.4239037 , 0.30094583,
       0.77644024, 0.46345658, 0.32846088, 0.79535684, 0.4961307 ,
       0.78847807, 0.24505589, 0.72914875, 0.57093723, 0.09372313,
       0.76784179, 0.54428203, 0.28030954, 0.54342218, 0.28460877,
       0.7566638 , 0.54686156, 0.34995701, 0.20894239, 0.68099742,
       0.17196905, 0.73774721, 0.3877902 , 0.71195185, 0.36285469,
       0.19862425, 0.67153912, 0.42820292, 0.81857266, 0.40326741,
       0.77815993, 0.75150473, 0.13757524, 0.        , 0.1900258 ,
       0.16766982, 0.03095443, 0.48323302, 0.6672399 , 0.4144454 ,
       0.4049871 , 0.74548581, 0.62338779, 0.83748925, 0.31900258,
       1.        , 0.69303525, 0.87532244, 0.65004299, 0.86242476,
       0.84092863, 0.3155632 , 0.84350817, 0.82975064, 0.59673259,
       0.23301806, 0.44196045, 0.15907137, 0.63026655, 0.22098022,
       0.76354256, 0.3327601 , 0.34909716, 0.23731728, 0.26741187,
       0.70077386, 0.09630267, 0.75494411, 0.4600172 , 0.79363715,
       0.46431642, 0.07996561, 0.20808255, 0.17970765, 0.41186586,
       0.44024076, 0.20550301, 0.75580396, 0.21496131, 0.59243336,
       0.4866724 , 0.37661221, 0.61650903, 0.38521066, 0.14273431,
       0.12381771, 0.46861565, 0.66809974, 0.14617369, 0.8194325 ,
       0.53912296, 0.50214961, 0.2605331 , 0.91745486, 0.55717971,
       0.40670679, 0.33619948, 0.44368014, 0.61392949, 0.34823732,
       0.81083405, 0.27858985, 0.71969046, 0.23215821, 0.68271711,
       0.42046432, 0.3516767 , 0.24935512, 0.34737747, 0.67325881,
       0.32760103, 0.63284609, 0.21926053, 0.41530525, 0.38349097,
       0.6938951 , 0.38091144, 0.07824592, 0.29148753, 0.23817713,
       0.28976784, 0.34393809, 0.66981943, 0.49183147, 0.41788478,
       0.33447979, 0.64144454, 0.28116939, 0.6749785 , 0.29320722,
       0.80567498, 0.46259673, 0.41272571, 0.92347377, 0.45571797,
       0.84780739, 0.8099742 , 0.91659501, 0.66895959, 0.6044712 ,
       0.29750645, 0.6216681 , 0.57695615, 0.25537403, 0.84952709,
       0.67669819, 0.48409286, 0.61306965, 0.74376612, 0.55975924,
       0.68185727, 0.79707653, 0.33018057, 0.17884781, 0.82373173,
       0.57007739, 0.42734308, 0.27343078, 0.5494411 , 0.18572657,
       0.65864144, 0.35081685, 0.13241617, 0.34135856, 0.31040413,
       0.71711092, 0.36371453, 0.18916595, 0.32588134, 0.71883061,
       0.36199484, 0.27085125, 0.58039553, 0.30954428, 0.76870163,
       0.70679278, 0.15563199, 0.15477214, 0.61478934, 0.43422184,
       0.38950989, 0.18744626, 0.38693035, 0.57523646, 0.50300946,
       0.23559759, 0.52622528, 0.0533104 , 0.82201204, 0.5855546 ,
       0.68787618, 0.4772141 , 0.50816853, 0.08770421, 0.25795357,
       0.14015477, 0.67067928, 0.20034394, 0.41100602, 0.63456578,
       0.88392089, 0.76698194, 0.65606191, 0.87790198, 0.72398968,
       0.88822012, 0.77901978, 0.72141015, 0.40584695, 0.25365434,
       0.95356836, 0.63972485, 0.36973345, 0.82631126, 0.53052451,
       0.68529665, 0.2433362 , 0.61822872])


min(noise_data['중식계']), max(noise_data['중식계'])
(0.1994840928632846, 0.879621668099742)

I think there is no problem on my two dataframes.
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(16, 8), sharey=True)

# 중식계 박스플롯
sns.boxplot(data=[noise_data['중식계'], cluster_data['중식계']], notch=True, palette="Set2", ax=axes[0])
axes[0].set_title('중식계 분포 : Noise vs Cluster')
axes[0].set_xticklabels(['Noise', 'Cluster'])

# 석식계 박스플롯
sns.boxplot(data=[noise_data['석식계'], cluster_data['석식계']], notch=True, palette="Set2", ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_title('석식계 분포 : Noise vs Cluster')
axes[1].set_xticklabels(['Noise', 'Cluster'])

plt.show()



As long as i use this codes for visualization, it is supposed to have two subplots by one figure(noise plot and cluster plot in left subplot, same to right subplot). There is only one noise plot by each subplot though.
It's really hard to figure out the reason!!! Please help me solve this one.

No data given to reproduce, but you can try directly without seaborn, it works with ax1.boxplot([df1["var1"], df2["var1"]], notch=True, patch_artist=True, boxprops=dict(facecolor="teal"))

Are you using seaborn version 0.13.2?
